# Dynamically assigning sharing reason to Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, scheduled-apex

I am trying to assign dynamically rowcause reason to my custom objects but erroring out like below:

//Smaple Map Format

```
recordIdsMap.put(objetapiname, Record);





for (String obj: recordIdsMap.keySet()) { //This will fetch names of objects defined in custom setting
    //if(i<10){
            if (obj.contains('__c')) {

                String objName = obj.split('__')[0];
                system.debug('---' + obj);
                access = 'AccessLevel';
                pId = 'ParentId';
                ShareObject = objName + '__Share';
                ShareObject2 = objName + '__Share';
                system.debug('PJJJJ' + ShareObject);
           }else {
                ShareObject = obj + 'Share';
                access = obj + 'AccessLevel';
                pId = obj + 'Id';
                system.debug('PJJJJ2' + ShareObject);
    }






Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(ShareObject2);

     //Here are i am trying to get my Rowcausereason in string 


//string RowcauseReason = Schema.sobjType.rowCause.ApexSharing__c;

        string RowcauseReason = Schema.ShareObject.rowCause.ApexSharing__c;
```

But its showing compile time error as below :

> Variable does not exist: Schema.sobjType.rowCause.ApexSharing__c at
>   line 264 column 37

Please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apex managed sharing doesn't work quite the way you seem to be attempting to use it. The only sharing reason that will exist by default is "manual". Any other reasons need to be defined on the Object's detail page. From the Apex Docs:

> Apex sharing reasons are defined on an object's detail page. Each Apex sharing reason has a label and a name:
>
> The label displays in the Reason column when viewing the sharing for a record in the user interface. This label allows users and administrators to understand the source of the sharing. The label is also enabled for translation through the Translation Workbench.
>
> The name is used when referencing the reason in the API and Apex.
>   All Apex sharing reason names have the following format:
>
> ```
> MyReasonName__c
> ```
>
> Apex sharing reasons can be referenced programmatically as follows:
>
> ```
> Schema.CustomObject__Share.rowCause.SharingReason__c
> ```
>
> For example, an Apex sharing reason called Recruiter for an object called Job can be referenced as follows:
>
> ```
> Schema.Job__Share.rowCause.Recruiter__c
> ```

See [Creating User Managed Sharing Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm?search_text=Creating%20User%20Managed%20Sharing%20Using%20Apex) for more on the topic.

Comment: I know that and that is the reason i created reason apexsharing in my case , but i am not able to get share object dynamically here:for example : Schema.Job__Share.rowCause.Recruiter__c here Job__share i cannot hardcode it

Comment: From a schema standpoint, you need to get the "sharingreasonlabel" in order to get the sharingreasonlabel__c. does that help? Try using Workbench to find the proper values to use for your schema calls.